# Vue JS dev server doesn't work in Atom

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js

I started my website project in Visual Studio Code and it worked fine for days. I found out about Atom and decided to move over to it. Somehow whenever I start the dev server in Atom, each Vue component spits out:

[Console output (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/rwaxpULw)

```
"Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding 
plugin"
```

and the webpage only renders

```
Cannot GET /
```

The dev server starts fine in Visual Studio Code but not in Atom

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with running `npm run dev` from CMD on Win7.
I dont know, as I did not require this plugin anywhere explicitly and when I started this error did not occure to me.

As i also started to get this error and I already tried setting `NODE_ENV=development` provided by this [issue report from the official repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5030), I tried playing around.

Finally i ended up editing the `webpack.dev.conf.js` adding this specific plugin to the plugins key as follows:

```js
// File header with other Imports
var utils = require('./utils')
// ...
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

// Then in Module definition
module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {

    // ... other keys for module

    plugins: [

      // .. other plugins

      // .. I copied this line from the webpack.prod.conf.js
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
         filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
      }),
```

Well there might be better and more beautiful solutions.
This is just the one that seems to fix it for me.
As I am new to VueJs and I am only using the dev server at the moment with autoreload, other answeres might be bit more polished.